# std::stringstream to return char *

Tags: c++, stringstream

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
void serialize(std::ostream& os)
{
   int r1 = 10;
   int r2 = 12;
   os.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&r1), sizeof(r1));
   os.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&r2), sizeof(r2));
}
int main()
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   serialize(ss);
   std::cout<<" Buffer length : " << ss.str().length() <<'\n'; //This print correct length
   const char *ptrToBuff = ss.str().c_str();// HERE is the problem. char * does not contain anything.   
   std::cout <<ptrToBuff; // NOTHING is printed
}
```

How to get a char pointer to the stream buffer?
**The problem is `std::cout << ptrToBuff; does not print anything`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer to the stream will leave a dangling pointer, you can copy the string though:

```
const std::string s = ss.str();
```

And then point your `const char*` to it:

```
const char *ptrToBuff = s.c_str();
```

In your `serialize` function you should use `<<` operator to write to ostream:

```
os << r1 << " " << sizeof(r1) << std::endl;
os << r2 << " " << sizeof(r2) << std::endl;
```

So the whole code will be: ([see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c821165c5446e2bb))

```
void serialize(std::ostream& os)
{
   int r1 = 10;
   int r2 = 12;
   os << r1 << " " << sizeof(r1) << std::endl;
   os << r2 << " " << sizeof(r2) << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   serialize(ss);  
   std::cout<<"Buffer length : " << ss.str().length() <<'\n';
   const std::string s = ss.str(); 
   const char *ptrToBuff = s.c_str();
   std::cout << ptrToBuff; 
}
```

Comment: @user3059007 you're right, I edited the post with the solution.